# Loop with two table and last row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build a formula:

```
=BDS(Bonds!J2& " ISIN","ISSUE_UNDERWRITER","Headers","Y")
```

In one sheet that takes a unique identifier from another table. 
These formula builds me a table. After it builds me the table, I need to take the next row in the other sheet:

```
=BDS(Bonds!J3& " ISIN","ISSUE_UNDERWRITER","Headers","Y")
```

Then insert that formula a the end of the previous table built by the previous formula.

What I tried was getting the last row and then offsetting it by one, but I'm trying to figure out how to loop through it.

This is what i have tried:

```
Sub Formula2()Formula2 Macro 
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=BDS(Bonds!R[1]C[9]& "" ISIN"",""ISSUE_UNDERWRITER"",""Headers"",""Y"")"
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=BDS(Bonds!R[-53]C10& "" ISIN"",""ISSUE_UNDERWRITER"",""Headers"",""Y"")"
Range("A57").Select
End Sub
```

[Image of Table, Im trying to iterate through the ISIN Column. It is column "J"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xdUm.png)

Comment: Please provide samples of your code, the 2 tables, and the desired result

Comment: Just did Tony M. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although `selection` and `.select` are used by the macro recorder, they cause big problems when developing code. It's worth your time to learn how to replace them with `range` objects.  So, while I'm not directly answering your question, I'm trying to give you the tools to do so.

I've shown an example below to illustrate (although I do not work with the BDS() function so I'm undoubtedly getting the details wrong). The main point is that if you learn to move around using the `range` object you'll be much better off.

```
Sub formula()
Dim r As Range, sh As Worksheet, bondR As Range, bondSh as Worksheet
set sh = ActiveSheet
set r = sh.range("A1")
Set bondSh = Worksheets("Bonds")
Set bondR = bondSh.Range("J1")
For i = 1 To 10
  r.formula = "=BDS(bondR.offset(i,0) & "" ISIN"",""ISSUE_UNDERWRITER"",""Headers"",""Y"")"
  Set r = r.Offset(i, 0)
Next i
End Sub
```

Here I'm defining one range object, `r`, to track the location on the active sheet, and another, `bondR`, for the location on the "Bonds" sheet. Once the initial locations of these ranges are defined, you can manipulate them using the `.offset(row,col)` function as I've done with the simple for-loop, moving down 1 row (but 0 columns) in each loop.

Feel free to ask questions.